# Dataframe value comparison with a numeric in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with only one value in it and  I want to compare it to numeric value and raise an error based on it.

Something like this:

```
df=spark.sql("""
select count(1) as count_check from schema.table) 
""")

df.select("count_check").show()


if df.value == 0:
    print("ALL GOOD")
else:
    raise Exception("ATAR DATA MISMATCH, RESULT COUNT IS NOT ZERO!")
```

I am able to print it using show() but not able to compare properly as one is dataframe and another is an integer.
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need collect the Dataframe column value to use in python context

```py
df = spark.sql('select count(1) as count_check from schema.table')
value = df.collect()[0][0]

if value == 0:
    print("ALL GOOD")
else:
    raise Exception("ATAR DATA MISMATCH, RESULT COUNT IS NOT ZERO!")
```

Comment: I tried "value = df.select("count_check").first()[0] " to get the data and it seems to be working.

Comment: In both methods will get the same result, since your SELECT is returning only 1 row. And check your code, you're using the SELECT twice, only one is needed.